# How to change one param value and leave the rest params unchanged JSX typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, jsx, stenciljs

Hello I have a function in which it has several params, I only need to change one param value to "false".

```
<button onClick={this.search}>"testing the bug"</button>
```

```
  async search(e) {
    e.dsds();
    this.sdsds();
  }
```

```
 async dsdsd() {


    this.isLoading = true;

    let criteria = null;


    let resultsCount = null;
    let searchQueryString = null;
    let isDefault = false;
   
    try {
      await this.setSavedsddsSearch(
          this.dsds,
          criterdsdsia,
          dsds,
          this.dsds,
          dsds,
          isDefault,
          "SAVE");


    }
 }
```

I want to change the value of isDefault to true when the user clicks on the button, how can i make that happen

Answer (score 1):

I think you got confused because you can't pass any values from the onClick event to your search function? You can simply do this :)

```
<button onClick={(e) => this.search(e, true)}>"testing the bug"</button>
```

and with that, you can easily just do something like:

```
search(e, isDefault) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // use isDefault param like you normally do with standard programming
  this.testingMethod(isDefault);
}
```

**EDIT: so now you rename function to dsdsd but the fundamentally the same - here is how I would do it.**

```
<button onClick={(e) => this.search(e, true)}>Use default</button>
<button onClick={(e) => this.search(e, false)}>Not default</button>

search(e, isDefault) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // use isDefault param like you normally do with standard programming
  this.dsdsd(isDefault);
}

//isDefault is pass in as argument
dsdsd(isDefault) {
  this.isLoading = true;
  //other variable assignments

  try {
    // you can pass "isDefault" directly
    await this.setSavedsddsSearch(
      this.dsds,
      criterdsdsia,
      dsds,
      this.dsds,
      dsds,
      isDefault,
      "SAVE");
  }
}
```

Comment: but inside my testingMethod i already have isdefault defined. Also this search method is used by other onclick events where isdefault is not needed to be true

Comment: Sure, you can easily bound this to another button with isDefault being false like: <button onClick={(e) => this.search(e, false)}>Do not use default</button>? At this point I feel I'm answering how JavaScript function works so maybe I'm totally misunderstanding where you get confused.

Comment: tomokat i updated my quesition in other post. if you want to take a look.

Comment: Looks like you rename variables and function names but the code structure is more less the same - if you want to conditionally pass true or false, then most logical way I can think of is to make it a parameter to the function testingMethod (or now called "dsdsd") to take an argument "isDefault" and use it accordingly - I'll try to add that to my original answer (final try)